# Trouble Installing ydata-synthetic via pip and conda

Tags: python, windows, pip, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to install the ydata-synthetic package to my Jupyter Notebook and I tried both `pip` and `conda` ways and it still didn't work. I am using Windows.

Here is the error I am getting from using Anaconda prompt command

```
Pip install

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F18479A748>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ydata-synthetic/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F18479AE08>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ydata-synthetic/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F1847B24C8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ydata-synthetic/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F1847B2AC8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ydata-synthetic/

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001F1847B9208>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/ydata-synthetic/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ydata-synthetic (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for ydata-synthetic

WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.
```

````
conda install -c conda-forge ydata-synthetic

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done

Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

 

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

 

  - ydata-synthetic

 

Current channels:

 

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

 

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're

looking for, navigate to

 

    https://anaconda.org

 

and use the search bar at the top of the page.```

That would be great if anyone knew how I can install the ydata-synthetic package for Jupyter Notebook. Thanks!
````